# explain bash variable assignement output

Tags: bash, variables, variable-assignment

Can anyone explain me why

```
VBB:~ me$ test="zut"; echo $test; echo $test > test2; echo "echo test " $test2
```

output is :

```
zut
echo test
VBB:~ me$
```

and not

```
zut
echo test zut
VBB:~ me$
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `echo $test > test2` writes the output to a file named test2.

this set of commands is does what you would expect:

```
test="zut"; echo $test; test2=$test; echo "echo test " $test2
```

Answer (score 0):

Addition to first answer you can assign the value in the file a variable.

```
echo "$var" ; var= more test2
```

So you can get string after you wrote to file test2